# How do I test reducer and actions that dispatches type with payload?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

My reducer is very thin and my actions are very fat. What I mean by that is the whole logic goes into my actions and actions dispatches the already formatted data and in reducer, the new data is just spread.

```
async function setInitialData(dispatch,state) {
    // ... many things going on
    // ...async await what not
    const currentRate = await getCurrentRate();
    const thing = getThing(state);

    const payload = {
      currentRate,
      thing,
      isLoading: false,
    };
    dispatch({
      type: ActionTypes.SET_INITIAL_DATA_SUCCESS,
      payload,
    });
}
```

and reducer is just:

```
case ActionTypes.SET_INITIAL_DATA_SUCCESS: {
  return {...state, ...action.payload};
}
```

how to I mock, spy, test these actions? I guess I want to:

1) mock async functions and the returned values

2) make sure these values are dispatched and the state is updated

How do I go about mocking these with jest? So far I come with:

```
jest.mock('./actions');

const dispatch = jest.fn();

it('setInitialData is called', () => {
  setInitialData(dispatch);
  expect(setInitialData).toBeCalledWith(dispatch);
});
```

I'm not too familiar with mocking and testing. I appreciate your help.

I'm NOT using redux in this example. This is React useReducer.